# NeuralNet regression, input normalization/ouput denormalization and role of activation funcions?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, normalization, denormalization

Given a training dataset, Xtrain (m x n) and ytrain(m,) and some neural net sequential model.

When and to what range does the training data have to be normalized too? How should predicted values be denormalized? And how do the choices of activation functions of different layers effect this?

- do we have to normalize the Xtrain data?
- does the range we normalize to, for example [0-1], [-1,1], [-5,5], [0,) depend on the input layers activation function domain? or do all activation functions impact it, therefore it should be normalized to the common range of all activation functions in the model?

and for the target (ytrain) used in training:

- does that have to denormalized?
- does it have to be normalized to the range of output layers activation function or common range of all layers?

very confused, so shedding any light on this for me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Do we have to normalize the Xtrain data?**
- Yes, we have to

**Does the range we normalize depend on the input layers activation function?**
- No, it doesn't

**Does that have to denormalized?**
- No

**Does it have to be normalized to the range of output layers activation function or common range of all layers?**
- Actually, I didn't get the question. But let me explain how normalization works.

---

The main aim of normalization - bring features to a single view. Standardization improves the numerical stability of your model. If you have different features (e.g. some numeric columns in range between 1000 and 20000, some numeric columns in range between -10 and 5, some boolean columns, etc.) you must make a standardization. This will turn your very different into similar ones.

But why do we need it? In neural networks every neuron takes features and weights as input:
`g(X) = X^T * w`
So, if some of your features is bigger than others, the model will pay more attention to large numbers.

Speaking about **denormalization**. Do we need to denormalizate *y* values? No, we don't. Since we didn't normalize *y_train* features, which the model was trained on, we don't need to denormalizate predicted values.

Comment: Thanks, the domain/range of the activation functions still confuses me. lets says a neuron in first hidden layer uses sigmoid activation, therefore it output values in [0,1] range. so shouldnt we have had to normalize y in that range so we can use same parameters we normalized to denormalize it? otherwise how would we be able to denormalize the outputs of that neuron

Comment: In case you want to predict values greater than 1, you can use other activation function or do not use activation at all at the last layer

Comment: so it same to say that in any of the layers of our network, any activation function is used, y should be normalized to range that is common among all activation functions? (in case of default linear activation, common range is R so normalization not required)

Comment: No, you don't normalize y values. You must chose the correct activation function at the last layer.